# Parsing repeated output using regex and returning multiple values for a single key

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I need to parse the following output :-

```
|------------------------------|-----------------|----------------------------------------|--------------------|------------|
| Assembly name                | User name       | Path                                   | Start Time         | State      |
|----------127.0.0.1-----------|-----------------|------Shell version 1.2.1-13-09-27------|--------------------|------------|
|ng40core2                     |ng40             |/home/regress/ng40core2                 |2013-10-07 16:55:52 |Running     |
|ng40core1                     |ng40             |/home/regress/ng40core1                 |2013-10-07 16:53:54 |Running     |
|------------------------------|-----------------|----------------------------------------|--------------------|------------|
```

There can be multiple entries with different versions of ng40core in this output.

I have written regex for single line,

```
regex_list = ['\s*',
'\S+\s*',
'\S+\s+Assembly\s+name\s+\S+\s+User\s+name\s+\S+\s+Path\s+\S+\s+Start\s+Time\s+\S+\s+State\s+\S+\s*',
'\|\S+\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+\S+Shell\s+version\s+.*\s*',
'\|(?P<ng40core_instance>\S+)\s+\|(?P<user_name>\S+)\s+\|(?P<path>\S+)\s+\|(?P<start_time>\d+\-\d+\-\d+\s+\d+:\d+:\d+)\s+\|(?P<state>\w+)\s+\|\s*']
```

I want to get multiple values for a single key.

 For "ng40core2" - I need username,path,start-time and state

 Same way for "ng40core1" - I need username,path,start-time and state.

It will be really helpful if you can suggest a way to achieve this.

Comment: That is fine, ultimately the need is of multiple values for a single key (for all the lines in output).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `re.findall()` with regex for desired line

```
print re.findall(r'\|(?P<ng40core_instance>\S+)\s+\|(?P<user_name>\S+)\s+\|(?P<path>\S+)\s+\|(?P<start_time>\d+\-\d+\-\d+\s+\d+:\d+:\d+)\s+\|(?P<state>\w+)\s+\|\s*', text)
```

Output:

> [('ng40core2', 'ng40', '/home/regress/ng40core2', '2013-10-07
>   16:55:52', 'Running'), ('ng40core1', 'ng40',
>   '/home/regress/ng40core1', '2013-10-07 16:53:54', 'Running')]

Comment: Credit to @Haidro for pointing out `re.findall()` in another [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19246775/parsing-desired-fields-from-output-using-regex)

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to parse with regex.

Your text:

```
s = """
|------------------------------|-----------------|----------------------------------------|--------------------|------------|
| Assembly name                | User name       | Path                                   | Start Time         | State      |
|----------127.0.0.1-----------|-----------------|------Shell version 1.2.1-13-09-27------|--------------------|------------|
|ng40core2                     |ng40             |/home/regress/ng40core2                 |2013-10-07 16:55:52 |Running     |
|ng40core1                     |ng40             |/home/regress/ng40core1                 |2013-10-07 16:53:54 |Running     |
|------------------------------|-----------------|----------------------------------------|--------------------|------------|
"""
```

The code:

```
for line in s.splitlines():
    line = [x for x in line.split('|') if x]
    if line and line[0].startswith('ng'):
        line = [x.strip() for x in line] # cleanup whitespace
        assembly_name, user_name, path, start_date, state = line
        print assembly_name, user_name, path, start_date, state
```

The result:

```
>>> 
ng40core2  ng40  /home/regress/ng40core2  2013-10-07 16:55:52  Running 
ng40core1  ng40  /home/regress/ng40core1  2013-10-07 16:53:54  Running
```

Just for fun, I made a more robust function:

```
def retrieve(file_path):
    with open(file_path) as f:
        for assembly_name, user_name, path, start_date, state in parse(f.read()):
            # code
            print assembly_name, user_name, path, start_date, state # example

def parse(text):
    for line in text.splitlines():
        line = [x for x in line.split('|') if x]
        if line and line[0].startswith('ng'):
            yield [x.strip() for x in line]
```

Comment: Thanks @Inbar Rose, that was real quick and compact solution of my problem!

Comment: Note that there are still some spaces around the edges. See `print line` or `print repr(path)`. You can just use `line = [x.strip() for x in line]` instead.