# Parsing desired fields from output using regex

Tags: python

I need to parse this output :-

```
S1-link-id   eNB-IP-Address   MME-IP-Address    Facing  State
-------------------------------------------------------------------
303          141.1.1.2        191.1.1.2         eNodeB  Established
301          141.1.1.2        191.1.1.2         MME     Established
306          141.1.1.3        191.1.1.2         eNodeB  Established
304          141.1.1.3        191.1.1.2         MME     Established
309          141.1.1.4        191.1.1.2         eNodeB  Established
307          141.1.1.4        191.1.1.2         MME     Established
```

I want to get multiple values for a single id (first column).
For "303" - I need enb,mme ip addresses, facing and state values, same way for other ids.

regex for one desired output :-

```
\s*(?P<id>\d+)\s+(?P<enb_adr>\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)\s+(?P<mme_adr>\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)\s+(?P<facing>\w+)\s+(?P<state>\w+)\s*
```

Got stuck on how to proceed after this to get desired values for whole output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like your regular expression is alright, so all you need to do is use [`re.findall()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall):

```
import re
print re.findall(r'\s*(?P<id>\d+)\s+(?P<enb_adr>\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)\s+(?P<mme_adr>\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)\s+(?P<facing>\w+)\s+(?P<state>\w+)\s*', the_text_above)
```

Returns:

> [('303', '141.1.1.2', '191.1.1.2', 'eNodeB', 'Established'), ('301', '141.1.1.2', '191.1.1.2', 'MME', 'Established'), ('306', '141.1.1.3', '191.1.1.2', 'eNodeB', 'Established'), ('304', '141.1.1.3', '191.1.1.2', 'MME', 'Established'), ('309', '141.1.1.4', '191.1.1.2', 'eNodeB', 'Established'), ('307', '141.1.1.4', '191.1.1.2', 'MME', 'Established')]

Answer (score 0):

Even though @Haidro already answered the question, I wanted to impart a helpful suggestion for really long regexes like you have there.  Comment your regex breakdown!

I'll be the first to admit, I suck at regex. I always come back to examples like this and thank 'past me' for being diligent with documentation. The key is to use `flags=re.VERBOSE`.

```
_brokendown_for_joo = re.compile("""
        get
            (As                 #/1
                (Int            #/2
                |Float
                |Boolean
                |String
                |StringList
                |Char)
            |Required
            )?
        [(]                     #opening paren       
            ['\"]               #single or double quotes
                (\w+)           #Anyword   /3
            ['\"]               #single or double quotes
                ,\s*            #comma and optional spaces
            ['\"]               #single or double quotes
                (\w+)           #Anyword  /4
            ['\"]               #single or double quotes
                (,\s*           #comma and optional spaces  /5
                (\w+            #anyword  /6
                |['][^']+[']    #or any chars in single quotes
                |[\"][^\"]+[\"] #or any chars in double quotes
                ))?
            \s*                 #optional spaces
        [)]                     #closing paren
        """, flags=re.VERBOSE)
```

Much easier to read than this.

```
re.compile(r"(%s)[.]get(As(Int|Float|Boolean|String|StringList|Char)|Required)?[(]['\"](\w+)['\"],\s*['\"](\w+)['\"](,\s*(\w+|['][^']+[']|[\"][^\"]+[\"]))?\s*[)]")
```